# Как получить текст, находящийся внутри HTML тега Python

Tags: python, html, классы, bs4

Мне нужно получить то, что находится внутри **HTML** тега. С помощью **requests** я получаю код страницы, а с помощью **bs4** весь класс вместе с тегом. Но мне надо получить только содержимое тега. Пытался использовать регулярные выражения, но в содержимом может содержаться английский. Вот фрагмент с тем, что я использую:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(dd.text, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all("div", class_="flex-grow-1")
```

Вот то, что я получаю:
`<div class="flex-grow-1">   Some text... </div>`

А вот, что хочу:
`Some text...`

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: `find_all()` возвращает массив элементов. 
Вы должны пройти их все и вызывать `get_text()`

Comment: a[0].text.strip()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант №1:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(dd.text, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all("div", class_="flex-grow-1")
value = a[0].getText()
```

Вариант №2:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(dd.text, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all("div", class_="flex-grow-1")
value = a[0].text
```